# How to cleanly remove MacPorts

Tags: macports, homebrew, macos

I'd like to cleanly remove all changes made by MacPorts as well as MacPorts itself, to try my luck with homebrew. How can I do that?

Answer (score 21):

The [MacPort documentation](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) advises to use your Terminal and type:
`sudo port -fp uninstall installed`

and with this command, all remaining items will be deleted:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local
sudo rm -rf /Applications/DarwinPorts
sudo rm -rf /Applications/MacPorts
sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup
sudo rm -rf /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0
sudo rm -rf /Library/Tcl/macports1.0
sudo rm -rf ~/.macports
```

**Warning**: Don't run a `sudo` command, especially a `rm -rf` one, unless you know what it's doing.

Comment: Just make absolutely sure the first line ends in a *backslash* and not a forward slash!

Comment: True that. I'll add it in my answer.

Comment: I got this error `Error: No ports matched the given expression` when used `sudo port -fp uninstall installed`. What might be the possible reason?

Comment: thnaks for the answer, what I was looking for, I got from here. Great!!!

Comment: Is `/opt/local` used for anything besides MacPorts? If so, this seems dangerous....