# Is it possible to remove all installed terminal applications and extensions back to native without doing a clean OSX install?

Tags: macos, terminal, apache, php

Basically I would like to know if it is possible to remove all php, apache, homebrew, mac ports etc. installs back to native without doing a clean install of the OS?

If not is the best way to go about having a mac in this state to do a clean install and then revert some of the folders back using time machine i.e. the applications folders, documents etc?

Comment: I general yes however it might be quicker to reinstall. you should ask a separate question for each one. macports has been answered [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82806/how-to-cleanly-remove-macports/82810#82810)

Comment: So as long as i reinstall and have a timemachine backup I can restor some files but not all? I obviously don't want to restore everything with time machine because that would defeat the object of the question.

Comment: I'm also assuming there isn't a simple way to do it all except reinstalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should be sure why you would like to do this and what a fresh environment would provide. This is going to be a bit tedious to do since you have multiple sources for the installs.

- For homebrew, follow the steps in [this answer to uninstall homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104346/31743).
- For MacPorts, follow the steps from the [uninstall MacPorts page](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) page.
- For PHP and Apache, it may not be simple to revert them to what the OS came with if you installed these outside of solutions like homebrew, MacPorts, MAMP or XAMPP.

The non-tedious way, which may take longer to complete, is to

- Clone your drive (using a tool like [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://bombich.com/) or [SuperDuper!](http://shirt-pocket.com/) or [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)).
- Reinstall the OS afresh.
- Then use **Migration Assistant** to bring everything over from the clone. You would have to uncheck the "Other files and folders on ..." option in **Migration Assistant** to prevent it from bringing back the locations that homebrew, MacPorts, etc., use. This method would also skip many files (like in /Users/Shared) that you would have to copy over manually from the backup.

Comment: If i use migration assistant to do this via a time machine backup will these issues persist?

Comment: If you uncheck the "Other files and folders on ..." option in **Migration Assistant**, it *would not* bring back your installs from the locations that homebrew, MacPorts, etc., use. But this method would also skip many files (like in /Users/Shared) that you would have to copy over manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a need to this in the future you need to plan ahead. (I do this for having a clean machine to make builds on)

The basic step is to create a backup of a machine without these installs and save that backup. Then you can reinstall from this backup (I do this into a virtual machine) and then apply Apple and other software updates.)

The you can add the software you will want to remove.

Comment: So my best bet at the moment is to do a fresh install? I basically had an issue with php, tried to upgrade to 5.5.5 and it doesn't seem to want to work. It might all be academic with Mavericks in the wings anyway but it might be worth my while clean installing and then upgrading to Mavericks then trying to upgrade php etc then...