# Finding All Files/Applications Installed With MacPorts

Tags: macports

I installed MacPorts last April in some delusional moment of thinking I was going to learn about the command line & compiling, etc. That hasn't happened and I doubt it will at any point in the near future, so I'd like to delete both MacPorts and any applications I might have installed/compiled with it. Where do I find the latter? And is everything in opt/local MacPorts related or do I have to go in and individually remove [all 335 results from lsbom /var/db/receipts/org.macports.MacPorts.bom](http://pastebin.com/4qJGh4bB), preserving non-MacPorts-related items in opt/local?

Comment: There is no easy way to find all the code you compiled which uses Macports but if did not learn re command line/compiling what could there be. Notthing installed should use Macports (there are a few badly done installs that od but these should be treated as bugs) If question is to delete Macports then it is a duplicate and can be deleted in one long line

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cleanly remove MacPorts](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82806/how-to-cleanly-remove-macports)

Comment: The linked question does not answer whether all 335 files need to be individually deleted nor does it answer where any applications or scripts that might be dependent upon MacPorts reside. Thanks

Comment: It does answer the first - it deletes all macports